# Cannot find html file from another folder

Tags: go

I've recently changed the file structure of my project and now I cannot seem to get my html files to load properly.

I have followed the advice of a couple of different answers on this similar topic to no avail.

In regards to file structure, `getIndexPageHandler` is in `src/controllers/index.go` and `index.html` is in `src/views/index.html`

Also, when I use `fmt.Println(filepath.Join(cwd, "./views/index.html"))` it returns `C:\Projects\Go\src\views\index.html`

This confuses me, that's the direct path of the file so why is it telling me that index.html cannot be found whenever I try to navigate to it? Also I didn't post the router that calls this on the `/index` route but this exact block of code worked before when the html files were in the same directory as my controller files so I believe the error is in this block.

```
func getIndexPageHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    cwd, err := os.Getwd()

    utils.CheckErr(err)

    template, err := template.ParseFiles(filepath.Join(cwd, "./views/index.html"), filepath.Join(cwd, "./views/header.html"))

    utils.CheckErr(err)

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")

    err = template.ExecuteTemplate(w, filepath.Join(cwd, "./views/index.html"), nil)

    utils.CheckErr(err)
}
```

Comment: Just in case "C:\Projects\Go\" is your `$GOPATH`, you should know that splitting the source files of a **single project** into multiple dirs that are **direct children** of `$GOPATH/src` is not recommended practice. E.g. `$GOPATH/src/controllers` + `$GOPATH/src/views` belonging to one and the same project is **not ok**. While `$GOPATH/src/projectname/controllers` + `$GOPATH/src/projectname/views`, is **much better**.

Comment: Please tell us what exactly the error says when you print it, and also what is the `cwd` value you get back from `os.Getwd`.

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks for the tip, I will change my structure after solving this problem.

Comment: @mkopriva Also, my error is `html/template: "C:\\Projects\\Go\\src\\views\\index.html" is undefined`

Comment: Did you try `template.Execute(w, nil)` instead of `template.ExecuteTemplate(...`.

Comment: Also if you do `template, err := template.ParseFiles`, you've just declared a new value for the `template` identifier, meaning that after that line, inside that function, you do not have access to the `template` package anymore, and you also unnecessarily confuse other developers that might read your code. Instead use a different name for the `*template.Template` instance variable, like `t`, or `tmpl`, or something, just not the package name, that's too a bad practice.

Comment: @mkopriva changing it to `template.Execute(w, nil)` fixed the problem which is strange because the original code worked before I changed the structure. Thank you for the tips too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of the problem is that you're using `ParseFiles`, which uses the **base** name of the first file to set the returned `*template.Template`'s name.

From the docs:

> ParseFiles creates a new Template and parses the template definitions
>   from the named files. The returned template's name will have the
>   (base) name and (parsed) contents of the first file.

The second part is that you're using `ExecuteTemplate` passing the full path as the second argument while the docs say that its second argument should be the **name** of the template to execute.

the docs:

> ExecuteTemplate applies the template associated with t that has the
>   given name to the specified data object and writes the output to wr.

Couple ways to fix this:

```
// the name of t becomes the base of first file, which is "index.html"
t, err := template.ParseFiles(filepath.Join(cwd, "./views/index.html"), filepath.Join(cwd, "./views/header.html"))
utils.CheckErr(err)
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
// use the base name of the first file from ParseFiles
err = t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", nil)
utils.CheckErr(err)
```

Or

```
// specify desired name using New
t, err := template.New("my_template").ParseFiles(filepath.Join(cwd, "./views/index.html"), filepath.Join(cwd, "./views/header.html"))
utils.CheckErr(err)
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
// use the name specified with New
err = t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "my_template", nil)
utils.CheckErr(err)
```

Or

```
// don't care about name because we'll use Execute instead of ExecuteTemplate
t, err := template.ParseFiles(filepath.Join(cwd, "./views/index.html"), filepath.Join(cwd, "./views/header.html"))
utils.CheckErr(err)
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
// call Execute
err = t.Execute(w, nil)
utils.CheckErr(err)
```

Read more:

- https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#New
- https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#ParseFiles
- https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.ParseFiles
- https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Execute
- https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.ExecuteTemplate

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two dots, for one directory up.

```
"../views/index.html"
```

Comment: This makes it attempt to look for `C:\Projects\Go\views\index.html` bypassing the `src` folder.